# Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references

Tags: java, document, dtd

When I parse my xml file (variable f) in this method, I get an error

> C:\Documents and Settings\joe\Desktop\aicpcudev\OnlineModule\map.dtd (The system cannot find the path specified)

I know I do not have the dtd, nor do I need it.  How can I parse this File object into a Document object while ignoring DTD reference errors?

```
private static Document getDoc(File f, String docId) throws Exception{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(f);


    return doc;
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A similar approach to the one suggested by [@anjanb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilderparse-ignore-dtd-references#155330)

```
    builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
        @Override
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                throws SAXException, IOException {
            if (systemId.contains("foo.dtd")) {
                return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
```

I found that simply returning an empty InputSource worked just as well?

Comment: Setting the features on DocumentBuilderFactory worked for me. The solution in this post did not work.

Comment: This also worked perfectly for me, even though I thought I didn't use SAX

Comment: Sadly this didn't work for me. I still got the error. @jt did it for me though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this is the approach recommended by _org.xml_ I think. It looks like there is a lot of material on this topic. see http://xerces.apache.org/xml-commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Catalog and the javadoc  http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html and http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/ext/EntityResolver2.html

Answer (score 149):

Try setting features on the DocumentBuilderFactory:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
...
```

Ultimately, I think the options are specific to the parser implementation. [Here is some documentation for Xerces2](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html) if that helps.

Comment: the last one (`load-external-dtd`) did the trick for me - thanks.

Comment: While trying this, I got a _DOMException: NAMESPACE_ERR: An attempt is made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces._.
I fixed this with `dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);`

Comment: Just to let you know, the last feature setting (as stated by @Amarghosh) works great with a SAXParserFactory.

Comment: For me the `load-external-dtd` setting was enough.

Comment: Using all the above features also makes the code to fail. Just using the last two feature(nonvalidating) makes my code work.

Comment: Per the most upvoted comment, `load-external-dtd` was the trick.  Thanks! I was surprised that a feature with `http://apache.org/...` in the name fixes Java DTD parsing errors, but happy to have a fix that doesn't involve exceptions or XML modification.  In my case, this fixed some intermittent failures when parsing Apple PLIST files and when either `apple.com` was unreachable or when `apple.com` couldn't respond to the HTTP request.  Much obliged. :)

Answer (score 6):

I found an issue where the DTD file was in the jar file along with the XML.  I solved the issue based on the examples here, as follows: -

```
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        if (systemId.contains("doc.dtd")) {
             InputStream dtdStream = MyClass.class
                     .getResourceAsStream("/my/package/doc.dtd");
             return new InputSource(dtdStream);
         } else {
             return null;
         }
      }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

**Source XML (With DTD)**

```
<!DOCTYPE MYSERVICE SYSTEM "./MYSERVICE.DTD">
<MYACCSERVICE>
   <REQ_PAYLOAD>
      <ACCOUNT>1234567890</ACCOUNT>
      <BRANCH>001</BRANCH>
      <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
      <TRANS_REFERENCE>201611100000777</TRANS_REFERENCE>
   </REQ_PAYLOAD>
</MYACCSERVICE>
```

Java DOM implementation for accepting above XML as String  and removing DTD declaration

```
public Document removeDTDFromXML(String payload) throws Exception {

    System.out.println("### Payload received in XMlDTDRemover: " + payload);

    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        dbf.setValidating(false);
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
        dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(payload));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        System.out.println("Parse Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println("SAX Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO Error: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return doc;

}
```

**Destination XML (Without DTD)**

```
<MYACCSERVICE>
   <REQ_PAYLOAD>
      <ACCOUNT>1234567890</ACCOUNT>
      <BRANCH>001</BRANCH>
      <CURRENCY>USD</CURRENCY>
      <TRANS_REFERENCE>201611100000777</TRANS_REFERENCE>
   </REQ_PAYLOAD>
</MYACCSERVICE>
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know I do not have the dtd, nor do I need it.

I am suspicious of this statement; does your document contain any entity references? If so, you definitely need the DTD.

Anyway, the usual way of preventing this from happening is using an XML catalog to define a local path for "map.dtd".

Answer (score 2):

here's another user who got the same issue : http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284209&forumID=34

user ddssot on that post says

```
myDocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
          public InputSource resolveEntity(java.lang.String publicId, java.lang.String systemId)
                 throws SAXException, java.io.IOException
          {
            if (publicId.equals("--myDTDpublicID--"))
              // this deactivates the open office DTD
              return new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>".getBytes()));
            else return null;
          }
});
```

The user further mentions "As you can see, when the parser hits the DTD, the entity resolver is called. I recognize my DTD with its specific ID and return an empty XML doc instead of the real DTD, stopping all validation..."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with sonarqube, and sonarlint for eclipse showed me **Untrusted XML should be parsed without resolving external data (squid:S2755)**

I managed to solve it using:

```
    factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);

    // If you can't completely disable DTDs, then at least do the following:
    // Xerces 1 - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#external-general-entities
    // Xerces 2 - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#external-general-entities
    // JDK7+ - http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);

    // Xerces 1 - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#external-parameter-entities
    // Xerces 2 - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#external-parameter-entities
    // JDK7+ - http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities
    factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);

    // Disable external DTDs as well
    factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

    // and these as well, per Timothy Morgan's 2014 paper: "XML Schema, DTD, and Entity Attacks"
    factory.setXIncludeAware(false);
    factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
```