# Referring to a local DTD in Java

Tags: java, xml, sax, dtd

I have some XML that I'm parsing with a SAX parser in Java.  It starts with this preamble:

```
<!DOCTYPE math 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN"
           "http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml3/mathml3.dtd">
```

How do I change this to use a local DTD?

I suppose I could do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE math 
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD MathML 3.0//EN"
           "file:///c:/MathML/mathml3.dtd">
```

Not exactly like that, but *something* like that.  However, I need the path to be independent of the user's system.

How do I use a local DTD with a path relative to the class path?

Comment: Possibly useful to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243728/how-to-disable-dtd-at-runtime-in-javas-xpath

Comment: Another possibility is to use an XML Catalog that resolves the doctype to a local file without changing the XML. This pushes the change to a parameter to the parser invocation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](http://xml.apache.org/commons/components/resolver/resolver-article.html) on using XML catalogs to resolve DTDs locally without having to modify your XML source.  The basic steps are:

1. create an XML file that maps system IDs to local DTDs
2. modify your code to instantiate and configure a CatalogResolver
3. provide the CatalogResolver to the XML Reader (obtained from the parser)

Answer (score 7):

When dealing with Web Apps, you can put the dtd in the lib folder and refer to it like:

```
<!DOCTYPE name PUBLIC 
    "-//CMP//DTD dtdName 1.0//EN"
        "/WEB-INF/lib/dtdName.dtd">
```

Comment: this is simpler than the first answer !! Thanks Hitham

Comment: I posted the answer as a web app solution and not for simplicity

Comment: lib folder should contain "only" libraries.

Comment: @Mehdi, DTDs are usually inside JARs, which are in the lib folder.  You just have to reference them differently as `jar:file:        
<absolute-path>/log4j.jar!/org/apache/log4j/xml/log4j.dtd`

Comment: Didn't know you can reference a dtd inside a jar, but it's a file appart, why not to place it in a path like conf/dtd and keep the lib folder for jars as possible.

Comment: I had to use a relative path "./lib/dtdName.dtd". Using Windows + Eclipse + Jboss.

Comment: For reference, 
I solved a build issue by updating the malfunctioning xml with

<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/aspectj.dtd">

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to provide the DTD file location in the system using classpath. So the DocType that worked offline would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: This works only with special [org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886453/hibernate-issue-with-using-http-www-hibernate-org-dtd).

Comment: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath I am getting this exception

Answer (score 0):

Also another way can be to keep the dtd at the localhost so that the final path becomes something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
          "http://localhost/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Definitely not the most elegant solution but surely does work.

Comment: Hacky but works, don't forget the port number if you have one (localhost:8080)