# Hibernate issue with using http://www.hibernate.org/dtd

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm currently using http://hibernate.sourceforge.net as my namespace in my hibernate configuration files which gives me these warnings:

> Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace
>   http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace
>   http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6
>   Migration Guide!

So I tried switching hibernate.cfg.xml and all the other *.hbm.xml files to using http://www.hibernate.org/dtd. However then when I try to generate the code using hibernate tools in eclipse I get the following error message (code generation works fine with the other namespace):

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration:
>   C:\dev\workspace\DataLoad\hibernate.cfg.xml Could not parse
>   configuration: C:\dev\workspace\DataLoad\hibernate.cfg.xml
>   org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception:
>   www.hibernate.org   www.hibernate.org Nested exception:
>   www.hibernate.org
>       org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
>       www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org

Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/findata?tcpKeepAlive=true
        </property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">xxxxxxxx</property>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
        </property>

        <mapping resource="conf/Alert.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Entity.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/FactData.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/TimeEvent.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/AlertTarget.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/LogAlert.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/RepeatType.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Schedule.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Task.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/JobQueue.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/LogTask.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Exclude.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/LogNotification.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Job.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/Metric.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/EntityGroup.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="conf/ExtractSingle.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had also some problems parsing hibernate cfg files in last time. The root of the cause was that the hibernate site was unreachable. After some googling and debugging org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver class, I realized that there is also another way, how to specify the DTD URL:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

This means that hibernate will load the DTD from classpath - it is usually included in hibernate jar in org/hibernate directory.

However, we use hibernate 3.5.6 - I don't hnow if this approach still works in the newer version - give it a try. The benefit of this is that you are completely independent on internet connection, proxies and so on.

Comment: Nope, does not work for me. gives a lot more errors.

Comment: In my case hibernate3.5.6 and some other jars are packed into a base jar names testbase.jar, when i give the mentioned answer my build is success but give file not found exception. If i give "classpath://testbaseorg/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" during build itself i am getting an error classpath is not a protocol

Answer (score 2):

Check this migration guide: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide36

You have to change the dtd url to http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd