# Load Hibernate 4.0 Schema from classpath?

Tags: java, hibernate, xsd, classpath, dtd

I just downloaded Hibernate 4.2.3, which allows you to use their 4.0 XSD Schema instead of the 3.0 DTD. This XSD schema is packaged inside Hibernate's core library.

I happened to come across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886453/hibernate-issue-with-using-http-www-hibernate-org-dtd) where the user was having bizarre errors when using Hibernate. The root issue was that, periodically, the Hibernate site would go down, and so the DTD URL would fail and throw exceptions.

The accepted answer proposed in that question was to actually load the DTD from the classpath and **not** from the DTD URL, since the Hibernate core JAR contains the 3.0 DTD in it as well.

I'd like to do the same, but using the 4.0 XSD instead of the 3.0 DTD, and nowhere in the Hibernate docs do I see any mention or example of this `classpath://` protocol.

So I ask: how do I load the 4.0 XSD Schema from the classpath rather than from a URL, in a manner that is similar to what the linked question above proposed for the 3.0 DTD?

Comment: Does [this thread][1] help you ? ;-)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11410346/2120773

Comment: @J.Buget - that link is the same exact link as what I posted above in my original question.