# Refer to DTD from an xml, when both are part of a plugin jar

Tags: java, plugins, dtd

My xml and DTD are place in the same folder. They are part of a plugin jar.
I need to refer to this DTD from the xml.
In this case what should the Doctype in the xml look like.

Answer (score 0):

courtesy of: [Referring to a local DTD in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331831/referring-to-a-local-dtd-in-java)

When dealing with Web Apps, you can put the dtd in the lib folder and refer to it like:

```
<!DOCTYPE name PUBLIC 
    "-//CMP//DTD dtdName 1.0//EN"
        "/WEB-INF/lib/dtdName.dtd">
```