# Modify XML parameter value using Java

Tags: java, xml

i am new to XML parsing.
I have one XML with parameters i would like to modify the paramter value from "abc" to "xyz" and proceed further. If string is modified then it has to update the XMl else it just show the print. But i am getting connection error. Please help to resolve the error and get the code executed successfully.

Full Stack:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
at ModifyXMLDOM.main(ModifyXMLDOM.java:29)
```

Test.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite name="Test" verbose="123" >
  <listeners>
              <listener class-name="ListenerClass.Listener" />
  </listeners> 

<test name="Test" preserve-order="true" enabled="true">
<parameter name="Test" value= "abc" />
       <classes>
         <class name="Test.Class">
          <methods>
                  <include name="TestMethod"></include>
                  
         </methods>
         </class>
       </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Modify Java.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class ModifyXMLDOM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Test.xml";
        File xmlFile = new File(filePath);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
        try {
            dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            String str = updateElementValue(doc);
            if(str != null)
            {
                // write the updated document to file or console
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("employee_updated.xml"));
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                System.out.println("XML file updated successfully");    
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("String not modofied");
            }
            

        } catch (SAXException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException | TransformerException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String updateElementValue(Document doc) {
        NodeList employees = doc.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
        Element emp = null;
        // loop for each employee
        
            emp = (Element) employees.item(0);
            Node name = emp.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getFirstChild();
            name.setNodeValue(name.getNodeValue().toUpperCase());
            return name.getNodeValue().toUpperCase();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it is trying to retrieve the DTD to validate the document.  Is there a way to turn validation off?

Comment: You need to show the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @tgdavies Full stack trace updated in description

Comment: This might be what you are looking for.  You need to disable validation.  It's trying to fetch the DTD over the network.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911348/how-do-i-turn-off-validation-when-parsing-well-formed-xml-using-documentbuilder