# ProcessEngine is not creationg

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

Whenever I am running my `Spring` application with `activiti` integration I am getting below error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/config/bean-daos.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine
>   org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine()]
>   threw exception;
>   nested exception is
>   org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Error while building ibatis
>   SqlSessionFactory: Error creating document instance.
>   Cause:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: mybatis.org

My configuration file for process engine is:

```
    <bean id="dataSource"           class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activiti" />
                    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
                    <property name="password" value="*******" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
            class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="apacheDatasourceref" />
                    <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
                    <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        </bean> 
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> 
        <bean id="processEngine" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="buildProcessEngine" />  
        <bean id="repositoryService" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="getRepositoryService" />
        <bean id="runtimeService" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="getRuntimeService" />
        <bean id="taskService" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="getTaskService" />
        <bean id="historyService" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="getHistoryService" />
        <bean id="managementService" factory-bean="processEngineConfiguration"
                    factory-method="getManagementService" />
```

Comment: `Cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: mybatis.org`

Comment: The error is not thrown by Activiti. Always check the error which is occurred first - Error creating document instance. Cause: java.net.UnknownHostException: mybatis.org.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462289/java-net-unknownhostexception-occur-when-read-mybatis-xml-file

Comment: I not using Ibatis in my application. But it raises exception like above while creating ProcessEngine