# Skipping DTD validation in DOM4J

Tags: dom4j, dtd, xml

I have an xml file that has a schema as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//NLM//DTD JATS (Z39.96) Journal Publishing DTD v1.0 20120330//EN" "JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd">
```

I have put `JATS-journalpublishing1.dtd` on the project root but still complaining with `dom4j.documentException`. My code looks like this..

```
SAXReader dom = new SAXReader();</br>

dom.setValidation(false);

Document document = dom.read("some.xml");
```

How do I tell the project to ignore the validation

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1185766/3190413

Comment: Thank you so much your suggestion works.. Greatly appreciate

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read well formed XML in Java, but skip the schema?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185519/how-to-read-well-formed-xml-in-java-but-skip-the-schema)