# Parsing xml data

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

DOes anyone know how to resolve this exception??

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\eclipse\WS\l\dblp.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)**

Even though I have given the correct path still Im getting this exception.

heres my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">
<dblp>
<article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Saxena96">
  <author>Sanjeev Saxena</author>
  <title>Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.         </title> 
 <pages>607-619</pages>
 <year>1996</year>
 <volume>33</volume>
 <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
 <number>7</number>
 <url>db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96</url>
 <ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466</ee>
</article>
<article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Simon83">
  <author>Hans-Ulrich Simon</author>
  <title>Pattern Matching in Trees and Nets.</title>
  <pages>227-248</pages>
  <year>1983</year>
  <volume>20</volume>
  <journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
  <url>db/journals/acta/acta20.html#Simon83</url>
  <ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01257084</ee>
  </article>
 </dblp>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing `"dblp.dtd"` in your `DOCTYPE` - do you have that DTD file in the directory mentioned in the exception?

If not and you don't have the DTD, try removing the `DOCTYPE` line from the xml file, or overriding the entity resolution to tell it not to try loading it, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1185766/1469259).