# Java How to prevent that an external library downloads a DTD file

Tags: java, xml, webdav, dtd

I've created a program in java that starts as JNLP (Java WebStart). This program can connect to a webdav service at the server, the JNLP was started from.

The first webdav request results in a security warning that some code tries to open a connection to w3.org. I'm using a external webdav client library which creates a document internaly. The library should not be manipulated or replaced.

Is there any possibility to prevent the download of the DTD from outside of the library?

Thank.

Comment: You can override the entity resolver. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references

Comment: No chance to change the required instance. Do not have access to the code that loads the xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution was to sign the external jar file and grant the required permission for downloading the dtd file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the library.  You can probably either disable DTD validation via a call somewhere into the library, or download the DTD it wants manually and place it on your machine somewhere for it to find.

Comment: Unfortunately there is now possiblity to disable dtd validation via a call.
Where is the place I can put the DTD localy so that the SAX XML parser will use them instead of requesting the remote one?