# Unable to parse JavaHelp's toc.xml

Tags: xml, dtd, javahelp

I wrote an XML parser for JavaHelp's `toc.xml` file in order to intercept some attributes I use in the `tocitem` tag that are ignored by JavaHelp. Here's what `toc.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'  ?>

<!DOCTYPE toc
   PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems Inc.//DTD JavaHelp TOC Version 2.0//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/products/javahelp/toc_2_0.dtd">
<toc version="2.0">
   <tocitem text="Introduction" target="intro" action="myapp.help.introAction"/>
</toc>
```

I am parsing `toc.xml` using the standard SAX parser. When I parse the file, I get the following exception:

```
myapp.help.TOCTreeFactory[WARN]: Failed to load TOC file from 'jar:file:/home/samad/myapp.jar!/workflow-help/toc.xml'

Caused by:
http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/toc_2_0.dtd
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at myapp.help.TOCTreeFactory.createTree(TOCTreeFactory.java:43)
...
```

I opened up the URL `http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javahelp/toc_2_0.dtd`, and I get a 404.

How can I resolve this problem? I tried downloading the JavaHelp distribution, but it doesn't contain the `toc_2_0.dtd` file that is needed by SAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning off validation in the factory?

```
SAXParserFactory pf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
pf.setValidating(false);
```

One other alternative...[Stop your Java SAX parser from downloading DTDs](http://stuartsierra.com/2008/05/08/stop-your-java-sax-parser-from-downloading-dtds)

Comment: calling setValidating does not help but the link help.

Answer (score 0):

When searching for solutions to a similar issue, I was first directed to this question.  The `setValidating()` method didn't work for me either.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155874/197011) to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155101/197011) pointed me toward [SAXParserFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html)'s [`setFeature()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setFeature%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), which did work.

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```