# unknown host exception while parsing an xml file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

when i am trying to parse an xml, i am getting following exception :-

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: hibernate.sourceforge.net
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
```

The code that i am using to parse the xml is below:-

```
File hbmFile = new File(hbmFileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(hbmFile);
```

i am trying to parse the xml that has been written for hibernate, actually it is a hibernate mapping file.

The xml that i am trying to parse is below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.hibernate.entity.Student" table="table_student">
        <id name="rollNo" column="rool_no" type="int"/>
        <property name="name" column="st_name" type="string"/>
        <set name="marks" table="table_marks">
            <key column="roll_no"/>
            <composite-element class="org.hibernate.entity.StudentMarks">
                <property name="subject" column="st_sub"/>
                <property name="marks" column="st_marks"/>
            </composite-element>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please help.

Comment: Got the same problem today, the answers here may work, but it is not necessary to disable validation, because Hibernate can resolve DTDs locally (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731499/4436313)). My DTD link was wrong: `http://hibernate.org` instead of `http://www.hibernate.org`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i used the following code and this is working fine for me..

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
dbf.setValidating(false);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
db.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
  @Override
  public InputSource resolveEntity(String arg0, String arg1)
        throws SAXException, IOException {
    if(arg0.contains("Hibernate")) {
        return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
    } else {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
  }
});
Document doc = db.parse(hbmFile);
```

Answer (score 16):

The parser is trying to download the [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) from `hibernate.sourceforge.net` in order to validate the parsed XML.

However, the DNS client on the machine can't resolve that host name for some reason (it resolves fine to `82.98.86.175` on my machine).

To avoid this problem, you have to tell the `DocumentBuilderFactory` to ignore the DTD:

```
File hbmFile = new File(hbmFileName);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

dbf.setValidating(false);
dbf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);

DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(hbmFile);
```

See [Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references).

Comment: is there any way to stop the parser to download the DTD.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating(boolean)

Comment: @frederic: hi i tried with code snippet that you gave me but now i am getting some other error.

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.setFeature(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

Comment: Looks like your document builder factory does not support `setFeature()`. Does that work with only `dbf.setValidating(false);`?

Comment: @Frederic.. i am not using any other jars for this.. i am using normal rt.jar. Do i have to add some other jar for the same...

Answer (score -1):

I am also trying read from a xml file with dtd tag

```
<!DOCTYPE grammar PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD GRAMMAR 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/grammar.dtd">
```

and code

```
File fXmlFile = new File(grammarXML);                   
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

I was getting the same error.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException:
```

The server where the code is deployed does not have access to w3.org. When i open w3.org in a browser, it is opening connection timed out page. I gave access to w3.org and it solved the issue.