# Can't parse hibernate.cfg.xml while offline

Tags: java, hibernate

Whenever I'm disconnected from the internet, I get the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: com/mashlife/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1542)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1035)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1017)

Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1532)
    ... 45 more
```

This **only** happens when I'm offline. Does hibernate try to read the DTD when parsing the config? What's the root cause here?

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/foo</property>
        <property name="connection.username">user</property>
        <property name="connection.password">pass</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- DO NOT Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <!--<mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorial.annotations.Event"/>-->

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Created issue: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-5760

Comment: show us your hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: @Bozho - it's the basic one. Attached.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Hibernate can resolve the DTDs locally (without a network connection).

Your DOCTYPE is using the new namespace (http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/) for Hibernate 3.6, so you might have an older version of the Hibernate libraries in your classpath.

I experienced the same issue after upgrading to Hibernate 3.6.8.Final.  I had multiple versions of hibernate3.jar on the classpath causing an old incompatible version of the [DTD Entity Resolver](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.3/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver.java) to be loaded which only works with the old namespace (http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/).  For reference, here's a link to the newer [DTD Entity Resolver](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/3.6/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver.java).

I'm using hibernate3-maven-plugin which has a transitive dependency on an older version of Hibernate so I just had to specify a plugin dependency on Hibernate 3.6.8.Final.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate3-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
    ...
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Oh dude you totally rock.  That just saved me so much time.  Reverting to "sourceforge" url's like "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" also fixes it as apparently those *are* found in the older jars, see https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=943281&start=0

Answer (score 8):

It is not possible because, hibernate jar files is also load the some dtd content but slow internet connection it is worked.

**(1) Hibernate Configuration File Location**

The first solution was to provide the DTD file location in the system using classpath. So the DocType that worked offline would be;

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "classpath://org/hibernate/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

**(2)Use SourceForge DTD URL with SYSTEM**

Another solution I found working is when I change the DTD URL to SourceForge and changed the declaration from PUBLIC to SYSTEM.

So below will also work if your system is offline.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

[Hibernate Work Offline](http://www.journaldev.com/2959/how-to-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-work-offline)

Answer (score 5):

- Another Way is You should download DTD file and set the file path.
  and also set the dtd file location in java Build path (eclipse).

### Hibernate-configuration

**Orignal DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" 
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

**Corrected DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://localhost:8080/YourProject/DTDLocation/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

### Hibernate-mapping

**Orignal DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

**Corrected DTD**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://localhost:8080/YourProject/DTDLocation/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 2):

in my situation:
JBoss AS 7

I check:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
```

and exclude dom4j in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            ...........
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: While the URL for the DTD, `http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`, resolves outside of JBoss in a standard browser to download the file, I was encountering an HTTP 403 error from JBoss when it would try to do the same. Correcting the URL to the one identified in this answer (`http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd`) solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone else ... my problem was that I was including the wrong Maven artifact. I was including `spring-hibernate3`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Replacing it with `spring-orm` fixed this issue:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check this site https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=943281&start=0

Hope that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Hibernate3 jar file, but the Hibernate4 DTD file. 
so the solution is choose one of them: 3 or 4.

BTW, I strongly recommend you using Maven for the jar dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an internal DTD (not pretty IMO) or download the DTD file to your filesystem.

Check W3Schools' for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping files, you must have the exactly SAME doctype as found in the mapping DTD's.

Then and only then you'll see that the dtd's found in hibernate3.jar can be found through the classpath, and running behind a firewall, stand-alone, etc. will be no problem at all.
No local dtd's in your projects to solve this issue, no code to intercept. :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

The same is of course applicable for the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.
My DOCTYPE was:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

It should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Can you see the difference?
The first URI has NOT `www` and the second URI has `www`

So, the `www` in the URI must be declared in the configuration file and in all the mapping files.

It is not your case (cause I can see you have the `http://www...` URI), but it may help somebody.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following method to skip the validation of Doctype in the Configuration file

Code:-

```
public static Document parseConfiguration(String resourcePath) throws Exception {

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();



        factory.setValidating(false); 

        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

         File f=new File(resourcePath);


        FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream(f);

        Document dtd = builder.parse(fs);

        return dtd;

        } 



public static void main(String[] args)
 { 

   Document dtd=null;

        try {
            dtd = parseConfiguration("src/hibernate.cfg.xml");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SessionFactory  factory=new AnnotationConfiguration()  
         .configure(dtd).buildSessionFactory(); 
/*
Now this code worked for me 
You just have to use annotation instead of hbm.xml file because I was not able to skip the validation of mapping file as it is written inside the cfg.xml file
Reply if you got some other answer to run hibernate application in offline */
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

use

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

it worked fine for me

Comment: Explain why in your question. It makes your get more points in reputation.

Comment: same doctype to be used matching mapping DTD's

Comment: Thanks Haroldo Gondim for ur words

Answer (score -1):

Alberto Daniel actually is right, indeed adding the "www." fixed for me the problem.

I guess, since the hibernate-core.jar file contains the dtd files, exactly the location http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd is treated somehow specially by the XML parser, so that the dtd from the jar file is used. I did not verify this, but it may be an explanation. However: Thank you Alberto!

Regards.

Comment: Hi Stephen.  If you're wondering why the downvotes, it's because this is not itself an answer.  When you have more rep you can comment and upvote the answer from Albert Daniel.