# HibernateException: Could not parse configuration

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, exception

I have a problem with my hibernate

the trace:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1586)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1212)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1194)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1188)
    at hibernate.filling.HibernateFill.fillDetail(HibernateFill.java:22)
    at scanningDirective.ScanningTimer$1.run(ScanningTimer.java:57)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1576)
    ... 11 more
```

Actually I don't understand why it doesn't work because time ago it worked well and after I've left the project for some time, and in this moment I could install some plugins to the eclips or anything else, Of course I understand that the code couldn't magically change. Well, how do you think what is the reason of such behaveour?

Sorry... how did I managed to forget...
Here is Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.5//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">1</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="documentElements.Header"/>
        <mapping class="documentElements.Detail"/>


    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

After I've changed

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.5//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Everything began working. I don't understand why it didn't work at the first time. Mabe I needed to restart project...

Comment: post your hibernate.cfg.xml here please

Comment: As the error says it could not parse the configuration, posting the configuration might help getting a grip on what's going on.

Comment: Do you start your app offline? It can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline

Comment: I think the issue is with: -//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.5//EN  it should be -//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN

Comment: yes, I start my app offline. well, what shall I do? I have another project with the similar cfg file and it works. so I don't know how to deal with this

Comment: Laabidi, I've just tryed, it didn't help

Comment: My last advice, try to change http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd to http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd

Comment: nope. (I try to lounch offline(if it's important) because don't have opportunity to connect the laptop to the internet at the moment.)

Comment: please see this SO entry: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline  reversing to sourceforge.net url solved the issue,

Comment: Sometimes it is sth. very simple: Unprintable character in there or missing linefeed after the last tag.