# org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

please help me in resolving this error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1494)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
at org.jbpm.db.hibernate.HibernateHelper.createConfiguration   (HibernateHelper.java:89)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceServiceFactory.getConfiguration  (DbPersistenceServiceFactory.java:75)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceServiceFactory.getSessionFactory(DbPersistenceServiceFactory.java:104)
at org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceService.getSessionFactory(DbPersistenceService.java:93)
at org.jbpm.persistence.jta.JtaDbPersistenceService.getTransactionManager(JtaDbPersistenceService.java:100)
at org.jbpm.persistence.jta.JtaDbPersistenceService.getTransactionStatus(JtaDbPersistenceService.java:88)
at org.jbpm.persistence.jta.JtaDbPersistenceService.<init>(JtaDbPersistenceService.java:50)
at org.jbpm.persistence.jta.JtaDbPersistenceServiceFactory.openService(JtaDbPersistenceServiceFactory.java:61)
at org.jbpm.svc.Services.getService(Services.java:160)
at org.jbpm.svc.Services.getPersistenceService(Services.java:197)
at org.jbpm.JbpmContext.getPersistenceService(JbpmContext.java:695)
at org.jbpm.JbpmContext.getJobSession(JbpmContext.java:639)
at org.jbpm.job.executor.LockMonitorThread.unlockOverdueJobs(LockMonitorThread.java:64)
at org.jbpm.job.executor.LockMonitorThread.run(LockMonitorThread.java:43)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection reset Nested exception: Connection reset
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1484)
... 15 more
```

I am new to hibernate and having difficulty in understanding what the error is. The jar files used for hibernate are as

```
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate3.jar
```

my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is as

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>   


        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
           <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/datacenter</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
         <property name="connection.password">admin</property>  
       <!-- <property     name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> 

   -->

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>      
      <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
       <property name="show_MySql">TRUE</property>
       <property name="format_sql">TRUE</property>
       <!-- <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule">hibernate3-  bundled</property> -->


      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
             <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <!--  <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTransla  torFactory</property> -->

       <!-- List of annotated classes-->
    <!-- Associations -->
            <!-- One to one -->
    <!-- <mapping class="Emp_Timecard" />
    <mapping class="maindoor" /> -->
    <mapping class="model.serverroom" />
    <mapping class="model.resourcelist" />
    <mapping class="model.timesheet" />
    <mapping class="model.maindoor" />
    <!-- <mapping class="timesheet" />
    <mapping class="Resource_list"/> -->


   </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are having an issue with connecting to the db properly. Are you sure the user name and password are correct? Or did you have an already a database called datacenter?

Also try changing the doctype  as

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Comment: i tried changing the doctype but still got the same error and yes i have put correct passowrd and username for connecting the database. already had a database called datacenter. i have checked the connection by running a separate JAVA program too.. what else can i do to resolve the error plz help..

Answer (score 1):

See [Can't parse hibernate.cfg.xml while offline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline)

Depending on your hibernate version it might be that hibernate is trying to load the DTD from the internet and that the connection is reset in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

to run hibernate application offline use 'hibernate-core jar' file it will work..
no need to change your Hibernate configuration file .Avvappa,BEL.

Answer (score 0):

change your Hibernate configuration as follows;

```
<hibernate-configuration
        xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

----------------------------to as below -------------------------------------

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.5//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

change ur hiber configuration i.e

```
<hibernate-configuration
    xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

----------------------------to as below -------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.5//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Running the program while your system is connected to Internet**

I was facing the same issue. And when i searched for the solution online found this thread regarding the same issue.

I went back and tried running the program again and it worked, the only changes made were connected to Internet Connection. I turned off the connection and again the program was giving the same error as you got.

My guess is the Hibernate configuration file is downloading the DTD from internet, and when it fails to do so it gives error while creating the SessionFactory object.

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
      "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"  
      "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

If the configuration file is not parsed, just check for the hibernate version. If it is hibernate 3 the DTD should be from **Sourceforge** website. if it is the later version the DTD should be

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM  
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```