# Running webapp offline causes org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: hibernate

I'm developing a jsf2 with hibernate and tomcat web application but when I disable my network adapter to emulate a enviroment without internet (for a presentation) the software throws the following exception on first access

```
HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.openSessionAndBeginTransaction(DaoHibernate.java:232)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.lista(DaoHibernate.java:126)
    com.wplexeo.model.Entidade.lista(Entidade.java:113)
    com.wplexeo.model.Funcionario.lista(Funcionario.java:373)
    com.wplexeo.model.Cache.getFuncionarios(Cache.java:765)
    com.wplexeo.controller.FuncionarioController.getLista(FuncionarioController.java:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1184)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:333)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:143)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:126)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:397)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1586)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1212)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1194)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1188)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.openSessionAndBeginTransaction(DaoHibernate.java:232)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.lista(DaoHibernate.java:126)
    com.wplexeo.model.Entidade.lista(Entidade.java:113)
    com.wplexeo.model.Funcionario.lista(Funcionario.java:373)
    com.wplexeo.model.Cache.getFuncionarios(Cache.java:765)
    com.wplexeo.controller.FuncionarioController.getLista(FuncionarioController.java:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1184)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:333)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:143)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:126)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:397)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
root cause

org.dom4j.DocumentException: www.hibernate.org Nested exception: www.hibernate.org
    org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1576)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1212)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1194)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:107)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1506)
    org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:1188)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:28)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.openSessionAndBeginTransaction(DaoHibernate.java:232)
    com.wplexeo.dao.hibernate.DaoHibernate.lista(DaoHibernate.java:126)
    com.wplexeo.model.Entidade.lista(Entidade.java:113)
    com.wplexeo.model.Funcionario.lista(Funcionario.java:373)
    com.wplexeo.model.Cache.getFuncionarios(Cache.java:765)
    com.wplexeo.controller.FuncionarioController.getLista(FuncionarioController.java:71)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:99)
    javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:178)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:554)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1248)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.setRowIndex(UIData.java:447)
    javax.faces.component.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:1184)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:333)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1457)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.StateManagementStrategyImpl.saveView(StateManagementStrategyImpl.java:143)
    com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.saveView(StateManagerImpl.java:126)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:397)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
```

And heres the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wplexeo?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&amp;</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">wplexeo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">wplexeo</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>

        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Escala" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Programacao" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Servico" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Evento" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Base" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Tecnologia" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Funcionario" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.ParametrosDoSequenciamento" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Indisponibilidade" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.PreferenciaDoFuncionario" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Empresa" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.ParametrosDoSistema" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.TipoDeJornada" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Folga" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Semana" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Bloco" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Plantao" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.AtividadeDiaria" />
        <mapping class="com.wplexeo.model.Usuario" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't parse hibernate.cfg.xml while offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why but changing the doctype in hibernate.cfg.xml to the following worked:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```