# Hibernate 3.0.5 unable to connect to Database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Hibernate is unable to connect to my local database.
I have used the same configuration file in a different project using Hibernate 5 and it worked. But I have to keep using Hibernate 3.0.5 in this one.

The projekt is set up with Maven 2.2.1 and Hibernate 3.0.5 on Eclipse 4.4.1.
It fails when reading the hibernate.cfg.xml and tries to connect to the database. The code only tries to build a session factory so far, thats why I don't have any mapping files yet.

pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.materna.azubi.pi</groupId>
  <artifactId>Parkplatzverwaltung</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Parkplatzverwaltung</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <PostgreSQLVersion>9.3-1103-jdbc41</PostgreSQLVersion>
    <HibernateVersion>3.0.5</HibernateVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${PostgreSQLVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>${HibernateVersion}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Main class:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
public class Testclass {    
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        SessionFactory factory = Connect.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        org.postgresql.Driver
   </property>


   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      azubi
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      azubi
   </property>

   <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
   <mapping resource="ProviderImpl.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Stack trace:

```
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFORMATION: Hibernate 3.0.5
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFORMATION: hibernate.properties not found
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFORMATION: using CGLIB reflection optimizer
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFORMATION: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFORMATION: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFORMATION: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Nov 16, 2015 1:52:04 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
SCHWERWIEGEND: problem parsing configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml
org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1098)
    at mypackage.Connect.buildSessionFactory(Connect.java:10)
    at mypackage.Connect.<clinit>(Connect.java:7)
    at mypackage.impl.Testclass.main(Testclass.java:16)
Nested exception: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:646)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1300)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1267)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1168)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1098)
    at mypackage.Connect.buildSessionFactory(Connect.java:10)
    at mypackage.Connect.<clinit>(Connect.java:7)
    at mypackage.impl.Testclass.main(Testclass.java:16)

SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at mypackage.Connect.buildSessionFactory(Connect.java:13)
    at mypackage.Connect.<clinit>(Connect.java:7)
    at mypackage.impl.Testclass.main(Testclass.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration/hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1173)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1112)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1098)
    at mypackage.Connect.buildSessionFactory(Connect.java:10)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Connection refused: connect Nested exception: Connection refused: connect
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1168)
    ... 5 more
```

So far i have tried to find any errors in the cfg.xml, reasons why it might not work with maven and if there are some differences between Hibernate 5 and Hibernate 3 which I overlooked.
I used to have

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
```

instead of

```
<property name="dialect">
```

but that didn't change anything.

The root of the exception is in Testclass line 16:

```
SessionFactory factory = Connect.getSessionFactory();
```

The called class looks like this:

```
public class Connect {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try{
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

I now know, that my program has access to the internet, and also that the dtd is accessable through the internet. 
I hope you can help!

Comment: Your hibernate.cfg.xml contains errors

Comment: I've been looking for them like crazy, can you name the errors?

Comment: Its some xml related error, check for missing < or unclosed tags or some weird character in opening or closing tags. As it says SAXParsing errors means looks like XML parsing error. please post the hibernate.cfg.xml here

Comment: I did. It's the third code in my question. Several validators didn't find an error.

Comment: <!--mapping resource="ProviderImpl.hbm.xml"/--> remove / from end

Comment: I didn't realise that was an error aswell. But since it's commented out it had no impact: still the same error, sadly. Thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Stupid test: what happens when you remove that doctype element from the hibernate.cfg.xml file? The root cause seems to indicate the XML parser is trying to fetch something from a remote host and is failing with a "connection refused" which is a networking error.

Comment: That threw a very funny stacktrace at me ^^ I'll look if something is wrong with the firewall, thanks for the hint! I edited the text for some more information about the root of the exception. I think the refused connection is the database not beeing connnected.

Comment: You can clearly see in your updated stacktrace that it is HttpClient that is tripping that exception. So no, not the database.

Comment: I have tested a lot of things. Now I know, that I do have a connection and the dtd is accessable. So that was not it..

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301294/cant-parse-hibernate-cfg-xml-while-offline

Comment: It was! It *sort of* works now. Thanks!

Comment: @N.Nowak What is "sort of" ? Can this be considered a duplicate or is there a notable difference between what you experience and what is described in that thread?

Comment: Actually it's not a duplicate. I solved it by reverting to the sourceforge links which got mentioned in the comment at the solution. The dtds can now be local, that's why it *sort of* works. It still cannot load them dynamicly but with the dtds saved localy it works.

Comment: (please, do the `@` thing I did; if you put that in front of a name that person gets a notification you commented). If that is true, it is worth it to self-answer this question with the details of what you did.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier versions of hibernate like 3.0.5 do not support the import of .dtd files very well.

This problem can easily be solved by using the sourceforge liks.

For the hibernate.cfg.xml use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

For any class.hbm.xml files use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping SYSTEM 
"hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

If you still get an error hibernate will tell you where it looked for the .dtd files and you can copy them there.