# How can I prevent Xerces from accessing the Internet for a System ID URI?

Tags: java, xml, xerces, xml-validation

I'm validating an XML file using Xerces and haven all the schema files locally in my classpath (using an XML catalog).

```
  Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
  validator.setResourceResolver(CatalogResourceResolver.getInstance());
  validator.validate(getSource(true));
```

(getSource(boolean) gets the SAXSource)

Normally, the system ID is some URI or URL.

Some validations take a really long time, and recently I got:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.openServer(NetworkClient.java:118)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:488)
at sun.net.ftp.FtpClient.openServer(FtpClient.java:475)
at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:270)
at sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:352)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.ValidatorImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(Validator.java:127)
```

So obviously, Xerces is trying to download the file.

How can I stop that?

Comment: I found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references).

Answer (score 0):

I have found this technique to work for me in the past:
https://rubenlaguna.com/post/2009-10-25-disable-dom-dtd-validation/