# I can not convert XML that has a defined DTD to Document type in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-parsing, dtd-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references)

Here is my sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE factory-requirements SYSTEM "factory.7.0.dtd">
<data name="product">
  <product name="container">
    <one>20 feet</one>
    <two>50 feet</two>
  </product>
</data>
```

When I try to pass this file into my Document I get an error .

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\johnB\workspace\project\factory.7.0.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

It seems that it is looking for the DTD also which I don't have. I just need to parse this file as an XML and get products. I will not be validating this XML against a DTD since I don't have a DTD and we only get this XML from our vendors.

Here is my code:

```
File fstream = new File("C:/Documents and Settings/johnB/workspace/project/factory_product.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fstream);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

What can I do so it ignores `<!DOCTYPE factory-requirements SYSTEM "factory.7.0.dtd">` when parsing?

Comment: I got the answer I was looking for. Here is what needs to be added right after dBuilder is initialized.

   `dBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {

    
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
      throws SAXException, IOException {
     if (systemId.contains("factory.7.0.dtd")) {
                  return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
              } else {
                  return null;
              }
    }
   });`