# Exception while pulling the message from service bus

Tags: java, azure, servicebus, jsm

I want to pull a message from service bus.  The messages are nothing but the XML.
I want to use the `PEEK_LOCK` option for achieving the objective.

For now, there is no message in the queue.  My code run through a schedule every 30 seconds.  If there are any message in the queue it will pull the message else it will print *No more message*.

```
ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
service.getQueue(queueName).getValue().setMaxSizeInMegabytes((long) 1);
BrokeredMessage message;
message = service.receiveQueueMessage(queueName).getValue();
StreamSource source = null;
ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
LOG.debug("Message: " + message);
// LOG.debug("message.getMessageId(): " + message.getMessageId());
// try {
if (message != null) {
    source = new StreamSource(message.getBody());
    StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer();
    String finalstring = sb.toString();
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource src = new InputSource();
    src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(finalstring));

    Document doc = builder.parse(src);
    String ecnNo = doc.getElementsByTagName(xmlECNNoTag).item(0).getTextContent();

    LOG.info(ecnNo + " Is pulled from queue "); 
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.info("XML Content: " + finalstring);
    }
}
service.deleteMessage(message);
```

If I remove the `peek_lock` code my code works fine.  With the `peek_lock` I get this error:

> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White
>   spaces are required between publicId and systemId. at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:749)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:351)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at
>   com.jci.subscriber.service.PLMSubscriberMSServiceImpl.azureMessageSubscriber(PLMSubscriberMSServiceImpl.java:160)
>   ~[classes/:na] at
>   com.jci.subscriber.PLMSubscriberMSApplication.getXML(PLMSubscriberMSApplication.java:118)
>   [classes/:na] at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na] at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
>   [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at
>   org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
>   [spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE] at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_66] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_66]
>   Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: White spaces are required
>   between publicId and systemId. at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(TransformerImpl.java:641)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:737)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_66] ... 15 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

According to the exception, per my experience, I think the issue was caused by validate the remote DTD schema of the message from service bus with `peek_lock` mode via `DocumentBuilder`.

There are some workaround way as below.

1. Try to use method `[DocumentBuilderFactory.setValidating(boolean validating)`][1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating(boolean)) to disable the validating for message as below.

   ```
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   factory.setValidating(false);
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   ```
2. Try to set a custom `EntityResolver` object for `DocumentBuilder` via method [`DocumentBuilder.setEntityResolver(EntityResolver er)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#setEntityResolver(org.xml.sax.EntityResolver)), please refer to the anwser of the SO thread [Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references) .

> `builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
>     @Override
>     public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
>         throws SAXException, IOException {
>         if (systemId.contains("foo.dtd")) {
>             return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
>         } else {
>             return null;
>         }
>     }
>   });`

3. Try to use the third party libraries like [`dom4j`](http://www.dom4j.org/) to parse the message.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.