# How to set system and public ID without validating or checking DTD?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

Not sure if it's just me or the API but I am simply not able to create an XML file without having either an exception thrown at me or the thing I'm trying to set (`DocType`)  not being set.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
stringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
stringBuilder.append("<!DOCTYPE document>");

String xmlString = AnnotatedDocumentTree.toString(annotatedDocumentTree, new SimpleAnnotatedDocumentTreeXmlConverter(), stringBuilder);

DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder icBuilder;          
Document finalDocument = null;                 

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

try {

    icBuilder = icFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 

    finalDocument = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));                

    Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

    DocumentType doctype = xmlDocument.getDoctype();                    

    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, doctype.getSystemId());
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, doctype.getPublicId());
    transformer.transform(new DOMSource(finalDocument), new StreamResult(writer));

    finalDocument = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))));


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, this way I'm getting an exception. I can use the `DocumentBuilderFactory` and configure it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155874/826983):

```
icFactory.setValidating(false);
icFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
icFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", false);
icFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/validation", false);
icFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-dtd-grammar", false);
icFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

but then `DocType` of my `finalDocument` will be `null`.

[Setting my own `EntityResolver`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/155353/826983) won't do the trick either:

```
builder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
    @Override
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
            throws SAXException, IOException {
        if (systemId.contains(".dtd")) {
            return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

because if I want to set `doctype.getSystemId()` I *really* want to set `doctype.getSystemId()`.

Is there a way to shove set it without this headache?

---

Essentially I want to parse this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE document>
<ds>
    ABGB <cue>: §§ 786 , 810 , 812 </cue>Die Kosten der ... 
    <cue>von</cue>
    <Relation bewertung="1">7 Ob 56/10a </Relation>= 
    <Relation bewertung="1">Zak 2010/773 , 440 </Relation>. 
</ds>
```

and transform it into this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ds PUBLIC "-//MBO//DTD artikel-at 1.0//DE" "http://dtd.company.de/dtd-at/artikel.dtd">
<ds>
    ABGB <cue>: §§ 786 , 810 , 812 
    </cue>Die Kosten der ... <cue>
    von 
    </cue><Relation bewertung="1">7 Ob 56/10a </Relation>= 
    <Relation bewertung="1">Zak 2010/773 , 440 </Relation>. 
</ds>
```

Comment: could you update post with your xml structure?

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? print the dtd declaration when using xslt transform  to serialize a document ? what is [xmlDocument] ? and [xmlString] ?

Comment: Still there is a not defined [xmlDocument] variable, is this the original document with doctype ?

Comment: thanks for the `hint` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me your code works if the dtd exists at the specified location (systemId), otherwise adding the entity resolver as in the code down makes the trick.

I don't have `xmlDocument` so I hardcoded the values

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>");
    stringBuilder.append("<!DOCTYPE document><document/>");

    String xmlString = stringBuilder.toString(); // AnnotatedDocumentTree.toString(annotatedDocumentTree, new SimpleAnnotatedDocumentTreeXmlConverter(), stringBuilder);

    DocumentBuilderFactory icFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder icBuilder;          
    Document finalDocument = null;                 

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try {

        icBuilder = icFactory.newDocumentBuilder(); 

        finalDocument = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"))));                

        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();

        //DocumentType doctype = xmlDocument.getDoctype();                    

        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "xdtd.dtd"); // doctype.getSystemId());
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "xxxx"); //doctype.getPublicId());
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(finalDocument), new StreamResult(writer));

        icBuilder.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            @Override
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
                    throws SAXException, IOException {
                if (systemId.contains(".dtd")) {
                    return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        });
        finalDocument = icBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(writer.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"))));

        System.out.println(finalDocument.getDoctype().getPublicId());
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println(writer.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
      xxxx
     -----------


     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE document PUBLIC "xxxx" "xdtd.dtd">
     <document/>
```

Also the option of setting the properties works, without entity resolver, must be done before creating the builder. Of the properties, only `http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd` is needed.

---

Here is the fun thing though: It's getting set on-read as it appears:

Before accessing `docType`:

[image]

After accessing `docType`:

[image]

---

This can be controlled, in Xerces, using [property `http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion`](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/features.html#defer-node-expansion), by default `true`

Comment: Sorry, but the point is to make it work even it this `dtd` does not exist. I just want to set it without checking.

Comment: is working without dtd `xdtd.dtd` existing, try to run the code

Comment: Yes it would work without that. But I *need* to set it. ^^

Comment: It is set. Output has doctype, doctype systemId is set to unexisting file `xdtd.dtd` and publicId to `xxxx`, what's wrong with that ? Code is setting `xdtd.dtd` with `transformer.setOutputProperty(..`

Comment: If you set  a breakpoint after `finalDocument = isBuilder.parse(...);` you'll see that the member `docType` of `finalDocument` is `null`. This is a problem because I am serializing this document in a later stage. Since it is `null`, the `docType`  is not defined after serialization.

Comment: To me is there. I have updated the example to print the doctype publicId, do you get null pointer ?

Comment: Oh - my - god ... It's getting set on access. I'll add this to your answer if I may. Your example works but I always stopped debugging as I saw it's `null`..

Comment: ;-) I think this happens for xerces by default deferring node expansion, see updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
Source s = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_SYSTEM, "my.system.id");
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.DOCTYPE_PUBLIC, "my/public/id");
t.transform(s, new StreamResult(sw));
```

No need for this to go via DOM at all.