# Karate - Cannot Validate XML response if DTD is not accessible

Tags: karate

I have a situation where I need to parse an XML response using Karate, but the reference to the DTD is not accessible. In other words is DTD required for parsing?

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I believe the DTD is required for validating a XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure. Are you facing an error if the XML has a DTD ?

Then maybe we need to make a change to Karate to skip DTD validation. I think this Stack Overflow question is relevant: [Make DocumentBuilder.parse ignore DTD references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155101/make-documentbuilder-parse-ignore-dtd-references)

If you can raise a ticket and provide a sample XML that has a DTD, we can fix this pretty quickly.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yes, if the XML has <!DOCTYPE USER SYSTEM "http://127.0.0.1:5000/login/dtd">
Then it tries to validate XML against that DTD

Comment: @AmirGhahrai just fixed this in dev. not sure if you are able to build from GitHub and try, I need to go offline now - but I can make a temp release tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @PeterThomas
A temp release would be much appreciated. 

Currently, I don't seem to be able to find a workaround on this. I tried sending the response to a Java function to remove the DOCTYPE but as soon as Karate sees that line it fails the test immediately, so I can't do anything further with the response.

Comment: OK, just now I found a workaround!
I declare the response as a text (sometimes text is very useful :-D )
Then I send that to the Java function to remove the DOCTYPE and then convert back to XML.
Seems to be working for now.

Comment: @AmirGhahrai great ! `string` should be better instead of `text` there is a very subtle difference.